# Is it possible to store directorys with hierarchcy in SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, hierarchy

I want to be able to pick a folder (with files and subfolders in it) and be able to store it as hierarchy tree in an SQL database (use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio). (It is required to be safed there as hierarchy)

To work out how uploading works, I figured out how to zip a directory, upload the zipped file, download it again and extract it to destination.
That means uploading a file is not the problem, but rather how to be able to design a table that can hold tree like hierarchys and how to seperate the uploading.

For clarificytion: I have lets say D:\Test\Subtest\Sub2test

I want to be able to safe the "Test" folder into the db with all its files. The subdirectory "Subtest" on the other hand should be uploaded seperately (Maybe into the same row and other column, or other table with foreign key to the original directory) with all its files. If the subdirectory has subfolders (in this case yes), the subfolder should be uploaded seperately again with all its files. And because (in this case) Sub2Test hast no more subdirs that would be it. I suppose to be able to zip every folder/subfolder so I can upload it whole in one swoop.

The problem is, as stated above: How to i seperate the folders and what database structure would be applicable.

Comment: Simply have a _parent_ field in your table and make a (nullable) foreign key to the same table?

Comment: @oerkelens I am rather new to DB and SQL so if you would explain it to a certain degree (doesn't have to be DB4Dummies :P)

Comment: Have you looked at FileTables? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server

Comment: @DylanNicholson Did not know about this. I will take a look!